# Regex in vim editor

Tags: regex, shell, vim

I have a file with lines like this:

```
artf20342 | [ SC2911 ]: PVT
```

I want to change this to csv format:

```
artf20342,[ SC2911 ]: PVT
```

Changing the `|` to a `,` and also strip the spaces.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? By showing your attempts and describing what parts you are having difficulty with, we get a better understanding of your proficiency and can give a more precise answer. As it stands, it just looks like you've posted a requirement and want someone to write your code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex on vim:

```
:%s/\(\w\+\) | \[ \(\w\+\) \]: \(\w\+\)/\1,[\2]:\3/gi
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Vignesh thanks for early turn around since your good in regex i can ask ur help one more artf19716,[SC2240]:HW version Dalmore 4.2.1 kernal 3.4.10 to artf19716,HW version Dalmore 4.2.1 kernal 3.4.10

Comment: @user3264858, for this case, use this regex : `:s%/\(.\+,\)\[\w\+\]\:\(.\+\)/\1\2/gi`. Hope it helps.

Comment: its says no pattern found

Comment: HERE is my original line    artf20324,[SC2870]:PVT 1.0 System Build   this has to be changed to artf20324,PVT 1.0 System Build  u can see the [SC2870]: is removed from the line how to achieve this

Comment: This `:s%/\(.\+,\)\[\w\+\]:\(.\+\)/\1\2/gi` should be working. I'm testing with your original string (`artf20324,[SC2870]:PVT 1.0 System Build`), and it's resulting in `artf20324,PVT 1.0 System Build`. What's the version of your vim? Type `:version` on your vim to check this.

Comment: VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Feb 17 2012 10:23:31)

Comment: Try this : `:%s/\[\w\+\]://gi`. Let me know if you still have issue with this,

Comment: Hi rbyte, I really learned from ur patterns i have a string SC2232  Can't turn off the DUT's volume when click the “sound off”  key which needs to be changed to SC2232,Can't turn off the DUT's volume when click the “sound off”  key so i have tried :%s/\(\w\+\) \(\w\+\)/\1,\2/gi
 an i missing something

Comment: @user3264858, if you're trying to match capturing groups ( `(` and `)` ), you have to escape them with a `\\``. Like this `\(...\)`. As your question doesn't concern about this topic anymore, I'd suggest you to create a new topic describing your new issue.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter solution: if all your lines look like the one you wrote, you can just use:

```
sed 's/ | /,/' your_file
```

Or in vim:

```
:%s/ | /,/
```